# Is there a way to Pre-Analyze a Python program for naming conflicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, lexical-analysis

One of the most frustrating things about programming in `Python` thus far has been the lack of some kind of "pre-analysis". In `Java`, for example, a pre-analysis is performed before the actual compilation of a program, in which things like name usage is checked. In other words, if I have called a variable `list_one` in one area, and say I mispell it as `list_on` in another area, Java will say "Hey you cant do that, I dont know what `list_on` is."

`Python` does not seem to do this, and it is terribly frustrating! I have a program that takes about 15 minutes to run, and the last thing I was to see at 14.5 minutes into it is something like

`NameError: name 'list_on' is not defined`

Are their any tools available out there can can perform this kind of check before the interpreter actually runs the program? If not, what are some ways to work around this issue?

Comment: That's not a "pre-analysis". That's *compilation*! Java resolves the bindings at compilation time, while python does it at runtime. In python you can create variables at runtime hence it's *impossible* to *reliably* tell whether a given variable will exist or not at a certain point in time in *any* given program. Tools like `pylint` work *most* of the time, but may fail in more complex situations(especially in highly dynamic code). By they way: you should do unit-tests, i.e. testing the single *portions* of your code(this would reveal this errors in less than 15 minutes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any static analysis tools for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered checking your code with something like [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) or [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I found a fantastic solution to this problem for those that happen to be `emacs` users. You can install [PyFlakes-Flymake](http://www.ymer.org/amir/2010/01/28/pyflakes-flymake-for-python-programming-in-emacs/). This is a great tool! It will perform a static analysis of your code on the fly, and highlight trouble areas in red. I suggest using `PIP` instead of the suggested `easy_install`. Other than that, it is pretty simple to get it up and running. And well worth the effort!